# How to remove U and Y characters for text messages to self?

Tags: sms, php

If I send a text message to my phone via php `mail()` function, I see a character `U` after the Subject and `Y` after the body copy of the email sent.  How do I get rid of these letters from the text message?

So, the text message is coming to me like this:  `Subj:TestingUHello WorldY`

I send it with the Subject:  `Testing` and the body:  `Hello World`

Updated with code here:

```
$headers = 'From: testing@yahoo.com' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail('myphonenumber@sms.mycricket.com', 'Testing', 'Hello World', $headers);
```

Above is the code I am using, and it is producing the undesired results as described above.  How do I get rid of `Y` and `U` characters?

Comment: this does not happen if you send email some other way?

Comment: No, if I send email with my yahoo.com email via web, to my phone, I don't have this problem.

Comment: perhpas plying with the header options `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Please post your code. The PHP mail function doesn't do this by itself, it must coming from something you're doing.

Comment: Code has been posted...

Comment: do you get this error sending the mail to a non-carrier email for example gmail, or hotmail - even try sending one to your yahoo account? There's a chance that carrier side you may need to do something a little differently

Comment: Ok, well the carrier is cricket and the address is `myphonenumber@sms.mycricket.com`, I send email to that address with yahoo.com and I don't get `Y` character after body of email, but if I do this with PHP `mail` function as shown above, I always get `Y` character displayed after the body of the text message.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: And when I send this same thing to my yahoo email address, I don't have this problem.  The `Y` and `U` characters don't show.  This only happens when I send to my cricket phone number using PHP's `mail` function